# How to combine two json apis in react based on id

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to combine two json apis based on the id value. Is there a way I could achieve that?
Thanks. Below is my section of the code I have attempted so far:

```
  const [data, setdata] = useState([])
  const [runs, setruns] = useState([])

  //get data from the first api
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/tasks?format=json');
        setdata(res.data['results']);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  //map the rows of data from the api above to obtain values based on id value
  useEffect(() => {
    data.map(row => {
      console.log(row.id)
      const fetchRuns = async () => {
        const res2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/task/${row.id}/runs`);
        setruns(res2.data)
      }
      fetchRuns();
      row.rundata = runs
      console.log('row:', row)
    })
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the second request in the first `useEffect` as well and then store everything together

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/tasks?format=json'); 
      const arr = [];     
      res.data.result.map(row => {
        arr.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/task/${row.id}/runs`));
      }

      const res2 = await axios.all(arr);
      setdata(); // here you will need to join both results, but to help you better we will need the structure of both
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have first an API call that will provide you with a list of IDs and you need to populate (get the data) from those IDS based on a second API call.

You need to pass "data" in the dependencies of your second useEffect. This tells React "whenever 'data' changes, please do the following".

Also, you should set the data at the end of your loop or you'll end up changing it every iteration with 1 value!

Anyway, you should probably use the "for await" syntax as async logic is not easily compatible with .map.

```
const [data, setdata] = useState([])
const [runs, setruns] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/tasks?format=json');
    setdata(res.data['results']);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
fetchData();
}, []);


async function populate(data){
 let populatedData = []
 for await (let row of rows){
   const res2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/task/${row.id}/runs`)
   populatedData.push(res2.data)
  }
  setruns(populatedData)
 }
   
useEffect(() => {
 if (data.length === 0) return
 populate(data)
},[data])
```

Let me know if it works!